# Storing internal: spinner value and textview to integer

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, integer

Have been googling for 2 days now and I really cant solve this.
Anyways, the method that I am using **works fine with EditTexts, but not with TextViews and Spinners.** When pressing saver-button **it crashes**.

*I am a beginner so detailed explanations are appraciated! Thanks!*

The Java saving part:

```
public void saver(View view) throws Exception

  { 
    String mag = readFields();
      saveToFile(mag);
  }

  private String readFields()
  { 
      int[] inputIDs = new int[]{
                                R.id.email_address,
                                R.id.text_date,
                                R.id.txtTime,
                                R.id.spinner1,
                                R.id.spinner2
                                };
     String outputMag = "";
     for( int id: inputIDs)
     {

         EditText textField = (EditText)findViewById(id);
         outputMag +=  textField.getText().toString() + ",";
     }
     return outputMag.substring(0, outputMag.length() -1 ) + "\n";
  }

  private void saveToFile(String message) throws Exception
  {
      String filePath = getFilesDir().toString() + "/contact.txt";
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
      out.write(message.getBytes());
      out.close();
  }
```

The whole XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AddEventActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtTime"
        android:text="@string/ch_label2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_date"
        android:text="@string/ch_label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/addeventname"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="text_date txt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="text_time txt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:entries="@array/country_array"
        android:prompt="@string/select" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:entries="@array/upprepa_array"
        android:prompt="@string/select2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttontospinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:text="@string/button_label" 
        android:onClick="saver" />
```

LogCat when crashes:

```
02-11 18:31:12.058: D/dalvikvm(7771): GC_CONCURRENT freed 67K, 2% free 9444K/9607K, paused 9ms+25ms
02-11 18:31:12.338: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:12.478: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:22.419: D/AndroidRuntime(7771): Shutting down VM
02-11 18:31:22.419: W/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     ... 11 more
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at apps.rasmusmyhrberg.smartcalendar.AddEventActivity.readFields(AddEventActivity.java:67)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     at apps.rasmusmyhrberg.smartcalendar.AddEventActivity.saver(AddEventActivity.java:50)
02-11 18:31:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):     ... 14 more
02-11 18:31:23.099: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:23.119: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:23.669: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:23.669: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:24.159: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:24.179: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:24.719: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:24.739: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:25.290: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:25.309: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:25.859: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:25.879: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:26.489: I/dalvikvm(7771): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 18:31:26.489: I/dalvikvm(7771): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 18:31:26.549: I/Process(7771): Sending signal. PID: 7771 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please provide a logcat with the error

Answer (score 0):

You are casting every element to `EditText`. When one of the `inputIDs` does not reference an `EditText`, the element will be a different class. `TextView`s and `Spinner`s are not instances of `EditText` and thus, cannot be cast to `EditText`.

You will need to look at each of the types you care about and call the appropriate method to retrieve the information you want. Then you can combine them together into an output message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand what you mean, but I dont know how to do it.. Thank you anyway